# The given path's format is not supported. c# discord bot

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

I've been trying to get a logging system working where the files get logged to the date.txt where date is the actual date. here's what i have

```
public void LogMessageToFile(string msg)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string LogLine = System.String.Format(msg);
        string path = Path.Combine(date, ".txt");
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"D:\Logs\" + path))
            {
                writer.WriteLineAsync(LogLine);
                writer.Close();
            }
    }
```

and the bot says Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Logs\2017-12-22.txt'.

Comment: edited for new code.

Answer (score 1):

The code `DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()` will return a string like "12/23/2017 12:00:00 AM". You're replacing the slashes, which is good, but the colons remain, and those aren't allowed.

If you are trying to create a file name from the date, I suggest you use a sortable date format without any delimiters, e.g.

```
var name = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt"
```

Comment: you were right, i was assuming datetime.now.date would just give me the date part. i also thought that adding true to streamwriter would make it create the file or add to it but it just tells me 
Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Logs\22-00-2017.txt

Answer (score 0):

I would replace these 2 lines:

`var date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
string name = (date).Replace('/' , '-');`

... with:

`var date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

You can reorder the date-part formatting strings ("yyyy", "MM", "dd"). It's common to order as year-month-day because files/folders sort nicely and then they're easier to work with.